# SBT / Ivy: xmlbeans library not detected even after it has been added to the dependency list

Tags: maven, sbt, ivy, xmlbeans

I couldn't access xmlbeans even after it has been added as a dependency in SBT.

Here's my build.sbt

```
name := "xmlbeans"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
libraryDependencies += "stax" % "stax-api" % "1.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.xmlbeans" % "xmlbeans" % "2.6.0"
```

And here's my code:

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println("hi")
  }
}
```

And the error message I got when running `sbt run` right after I performed `sbt update`:

```
src/main/scala/Main.scala:5: object apache is not a member of package org
[error] import org.apache.xmlbeans._
```

Is there some steps that I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was a simple ivy2 cache issue.

I simply deleted the `~/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.xmlbeans` folder and re-run `sbt update` and `sbt run`. This time it worked like a charm.